# Pass form data via Ajax into PhP

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form using both text-fields and upload-fields.

```
<form action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="textfield">
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I pass all the inserted data via ajax and use the data in PhP?

What I currently trying via ajax is:

```
var fd = new FormData($('form'));

$.ajax({
     url: ajaxurl,
     type: 'POST',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     data: {
           fd: fd,
           action: 'devplus_submit_annex' // a php function
    },
    success: function(response) {
           JSON.parse(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
           console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you facing an issues? Please list any errors you are facing

Comment: your action attribute should point to the php file action="name_of_php_file.php" and your Javascript code should probably prevent the forms default behavior

Comment: @JackSparrow I get the '400 bad request' error on my admin-ajax. I dit this: var ajaxurl = 'https://domain.be/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

Comment: FormData creates a full form submission data set already, you can not “wrap” that under an additional parameter name (as you are doing with `fd: fd`), and then expect PHP to understand the resulting data. This needs to be just `data: fd` in your AJAX call, and if you need to add additional parameters to this form data set, then you need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: @CBroe Okay, and where do I define "action: 'devplus_submit_annex'"?

Comment: You do what I _just_ said, you use the `append` method to add it to your FormData object …

Comment: @CBroe this seems to work indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The FormData constructor takes an HTMLFormElement as its argument, you passed a jQuery object.
For jQuery.ajax you pass the form data object alone as the data field
If you need to add data outside of the from you can use the append() method.

```
var fd = new FormData($('form')[0]);
fd.append('action', 'devplus_submit_annex');
$.ajax({
     url: ajaxurl,
     type: 'POST',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     data: fd,
    success: function(response) {
           JSON.parse(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
           console.log('Error');
    }
});
```